# ¿Como manejar los botones "aceptar" y "cancerlar" en JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java, poo, condiciones

resulta que si fuera un showconfirmdialog podría hacer algo como esto:

```
 int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Si usted cambia al usuario como bloqueado, estara dando de baja al usuario\n"+"¿Esta seguro?",//<- EL MENSAJE
            "Alerta!"/*<- El título de la ventana*/, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION/*Las opciones (si o no)*/, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE/*El tipo de ventana, en este caso WARNING*/);
    //Si la respuesta es sí(YES_OPTION)   
    if(resp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
       {box2="1";}//El valor de box2 sera 1
    //Si la respuesta es no (NO_OPTION)
    if(resp == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {box2="0";}//El valor de box2 sera 0
    }
```

Ya que se trata de un int, pero al parecer el JOptionPane.showInputDialog que necesito solo es compatible siendo Object, este es mi código:

```
 public String cambiarbase(String base){
 String nuevaBase = null;
   Connection con =Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");//Conectarse a la base de datos
    String SSQL = "SELECT * FROM conect";//condición sql la tabla donde esta mi resultado se llama conect
  ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();//lista donde almacenamos nuestros resultados
 
 //hacemos la busqueda dentro de la base de datos
 PreparedStatement st = null;
 try {
     st = con.prepareStatement(SSQL);
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    ResultSet rs = null;
 try {
     rs = st.executeQuery();
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 try {
    
     while (rs.next()){
         
       list.add(rs.getString("nombre"));//añadimos a la lista todos los resultados de la columna "Nombre"
     }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PortalJuridico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    String[] result = new String[list.size()];//declaramos result como string
    result = list.toArray(result);//añadimos nuestra lista a result
    Object opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Selecciona una opción\n" + 
            "para cambiar la base de datos", "Elegir",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,result, result[3]);
  nuevaBase = (String) opcion;
    System.out.println(nuevaBase);
 return   nuevaBase;}
```

Mi objetivo es que cuando el usuario le de al botón de cancelar, en lugar de que retorne nuevaBase, retorne de nuevo la variable base, pero no encuentro de que manera hacer la condición, agradecería de todo corazón su ayuda.

Comment: Sigo sin entender el problema. El método [showInputDialog](https://serprogramador.es/programando-mensajes-de-dialogo-en-java-parte-1/) retorna la entrada del usuario (es decir, lo que escribe el usuario) o `null` si el usuario presionó el botón de cancelar. Para más información, mirar este [hilo](http://www.edu4java.com/es/java/joptionpane-showmessagedialog-showinputdialog.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es cierto que esta linea retorna un entero, porque eso es verdad:

```
int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Si usted cambia al usuario como bloqueado, estara dando de baja al usuario\n"+"¿Esta seguro?",//<- EL MENSAJE
            "Alerta!"/*<- El título de la ventana*/, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION/*Las opciones (si o no)*/, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE/*El tipo de ventana, en este caso WARNING*/);
```

Y si, se trata de algo **DIFERENTE** a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, segun hasta donde tengo entendido en las pruebas que he hecho, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` te muestra siempre un `input` donde puedes escribir, y cuando tu le das a aceptar para que te guarde el valor lo que se recibe es un `String`, o por lo menos en mi caso eso es lo que me devuelve cuando lo hago.

Sin embargo, digamos que **NO** me devuelve un `String`, si no que me devuelve un `Object`,  el problema de que te devuelva un `Object` y luego asignes un `Object` es que luego puedes liarte con el error:

```
Object cannot be derreferenced.
```

Y esto es debido a que `Object` es un tipo general, es de donde provienen casi todos los tipos en `Java`, por lo que solo en ciertos casos como por ejemplo la combinacion de **Map** y **HashMap** es buena idea usar el tipo **Object**, de resto, deberias usar tipos mas especificos, por lo que te propongo que en las partes donde uses:

```
Object entradaUsuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog();
```

En vez de asignar como tipo un `Object`, lo asignes como un `String` y hagas un casting del otro lado por si depronto a ti por alguna extraña razon te este devolviendo un `Object`:

```
String entradaUsuario = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog();
```

Sin embargo me gustaría mejorar un poco mas esto, siendo que habra una **excepcion** si haces el casting directamente del otro lado, puesto que tambien tenemos que comprobar que el contenido de la operacion `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` **NO** sea `null`, por lo que, para corregir este incoveniente, primero quitamos el casting y luego mas abajo comprobamos que valor contiene en memoria la variable `entradaUsuario`.

Si es `null` significa que el usuario le dio en el boton **cancelar**, si es diferente de `null` (un string), significa que el usuario ha digitado efectivamente contenido, adicionalmente yo comprobaria que entonces luego que ese `String` sea valido y que el usuario simplemente no se haya puesto a colocar espacios en blanco o tabulaciones usando el metodo `trim()`, que permite quitar todos los espacios en blanco que haya en una cadena de texto:

```
String opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Selecciona una opción\n" + 
            "para cambiar la base de datos", "Elegir",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,result, result[3]);

//El usuario digito algo y NO le dio al boton cancelar
if(opcion != null){
   
   opcion = (String)opcion;
   //El usuario coloco algo que no sea solo espacios
   if(!opcion.trim().equals("")){

       //Aqui deberias seguir tu codigo al validar que todo es correcto.

   }else{
      //El usuario coloco solo espacios en blanco o tabulaciones.
   }

}else{
   //El usuario le dio al boton cancelar.
}
```